# Calculate max TPS from log file

Tags: bash, grep

I have this bash script to compute the max tps from an application's log file. The script works but it takes several hours to run on files with millions of entries. The log entries have the following pattern:

```
2015-11-01 14:34:20,969 TRACE [Thread-2868] [TrafficLogger] service transaction data
2015-11-01 14:34:20,987 TRACE [Thread-2868] [TrafficLogger] service transaction data
```

The script has a loop to grep for all possible hour:minute:second combinations and count the matches for each, each time comparing to the previous highest count to update the peak TPS:

```
for h in {00..23}; do
  for m in {00..59}; do
    for s in {00..59}; do
      tps=$(grep -c "${h}:${m}:${s}" $log_file)
      if [ "$tps" -gt "$peak_tps" ]; then
            peak_tps=$tps
      fi
    done
  done
done
```

This is the straightforward way to compute the max TPS, but I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize it maybe using some heuristics about the input: (1) the input file is sorted by the time stamp; (2) it only contains entries for one day (i.e. the first column is constant).

I've tried a couple of things: (1) Adding `--mmap` to `grep`; (2) pre-finding all the time stamps and only searching those:

```
for timestamp in $(awk '{print $2}' $log_file | cut -d \, -f 1 | sort -u); do
   tps=$(grep --mmap -c "${h}:${m}:${s}" $log_file)
   ...
```

neither has yielded much improvement. I'm sure this is a classic test question but I can't seem to find the answer. Can you guys help?

Regards!

Comment: I may not understand your problem, but is `cut -c12-19 $log_file | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1` what you're looking for?

Comment: @JeffSchaller  I think you want to switch the `uniq` and `sort` in your pipeline.  `uniq` only combines (and counts) matching *adjacent* lines.  `cut -c12-19 $log_file | sort -rn | uniq -c | head -1`

Comment: I would normally `sort` before `uniq`, but I'm relying on the OP's claim that the input is sorted.

Comment: Yes, the input is sorted on the second column (c12-c19), so it's OK to have `uniq` before `sort` in this case ...and yes, that solution works for me. I'm used to using `sort -u` and didn't know about the `-c` option for `uniq`. I tried it and it now takes minutes vs hours previously! Thanks so much! If you post the answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command snips out just the timestamp (characters 12-19) from the log file, then (since they are assumed to be sorted already), runs it through `uniq -c` which produces a count of each unique entry (timestamp). The rest of the pipeline just sorts the resulting output by the first (count) column highest-first and then displays the first result.

```
cut -c12-19 $log_file | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1
```

Alternatively, do a ... `sort -n | tail -1`